# Stack overflow error when loading a large table from mongodb to spark

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

all,
   I have a table which is about 1TB in mongodb. I tried to load it in spark using mongo connector but I keep getting stack overflow after 18 minutes executing.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError:
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:264)
at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(MapLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(MapLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
....
at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(MapLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$foreach$3.apply(MapLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
16/06/29 08:42:22 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 54692 executor(s).
16/06/29 08:42:22 INFO YarnAllocator: Will request 46501 executor containers, each with 4 cores and 5068 MB memory including 460 MB overhead
```

Is it because I didn't provide enough memory ? Or should I provide more storage?
I have tried to add checkpoint, but it doesn't help.
I have changed some value in my code because they relate to my company database, but the whole code is still ok for this question.

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val builder = MongodbConfigBuilder(Map(Host -> List("mymongodurl:mymongoport"), Database -> "mymongoddb", Collection ->"mymongocollection", SamplingRatio -> 0.01, WriteConcern -> "normal"))
val readConfig = builder.build()

val mongoRDD = sqlContext.fromMongoDB(readConfig)
mongoRDD.registerTempTable("mytable")

val dataFrame = sqlContext.sql("SELECT u_at, c_at FROM mytable")
val deltaCollect = dataFrame.filter("u_at is not null and c_at is not null and u_at != c_at").rdd
val mapDelta = deltaCollect.map {
  case Row(u_at: Date, c_at: Date) =>{
    if(u_at.getTime == c_at.getTime){
      (0.toString, 0l)
    }
    else{
      val delta = ( u_at.getTime - c_at.getTime ) / 1000/60/60/24
      (delta.toString, 1l)
    }
  }
}
val reduceRet = mapDelta.reduceByKey(_+_)

val OUTPUT_PATH = s"./dump"
reduceRet.saveAsTextFile(OUTPUT_PATH)
```

Comment: How much memory have you allocated it right now ? Look at the Storage Section on the UI to see how much is getting utilised. Also, can you copy paste the code you are trying to execute

Comment: @PreetiKhurana I am running it on AWS EMR, using 1 master , 2 Core and 6 task machine. They are all m4.large , which have 8 G memory and 30 G elastic block storage. I will paste my code below .

Comment: You do not have a 'default' case handling in your map. Am not sure if that can lead to some issue but please add it and see. Rest of the code looks good. Also, can you reduce/increase your memory settings and see if the problem still comes at the same point ( after 18 minutes/processing of same dataset).

Comment: Great thanks, I will try your advice.

Comment: I think you should increase the driver memory. I have the same before but GC Overhead after I increase driver memory it's ok.

Comment: @giaosudau Getting the same error even if I raise the memory to 8g, I also raise the executor's memory to 4g in another running, still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add another java option "-Xss32m" to spark driver to raise the memory of stack for every thread , and this exception is not throwing any more. How stupid was I , I should have tried it earlier. But another problem is shown, I will have to check more. still great thanks for your help.

Comment: please add this to the question (edit), not as an answer

Answer (score 3):

As you know, Apache Spark does in-memory processing while executing a job, i.e. it loads the data to be worked on into the memory. Here as per your question and comments, you have a dataset as large as 1TB and the memory available to Spark is around 8GB per core. Hence your spark executor will always be out of memory in this scenario.

To avoid this you can follow either of the below two options:

1. Change your RDD `Storage Level` to `MEMORY_AND_DISK`. In this way Spark will not load the full data into its memory; rather it will try to spill the extra data into disk. But, this way the performance will decrease because of the transactions done between the memory and disk. Check out [RDD persistence](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)
2. Increase your core memory so that Spark can load even 1TB of data fully into the memory. In this way the performance will be good, but infrastructure cost will increase.

Comment: great thanks, I am trying your advice to see what will happen. But does it means that spark have to load the whole database into my cluster? I mean, as I post above, I only load 'u_at' and 'c_at' from database, that is less than 1% of the whole database, even if it loads the 'id' from database, that is still less than 2% of the whole database.  I am just confused about how spark works.

Comment: No. it will NOT load the whole database but only the _dataset_ you are working with. And from MongoDB perspective, you are executing a query which will probably traverse all the documents in the collection. You can run the query in the MongoDB console and check the `queryPlanner` along with its `executionStats`. If it's performing really bad, them optimize it and check whether it improves your Spark job as well. Also, please accept the answer if this really helps you.

Comment: I am still checking because MEMORY_AND_DISK didn't help. I am trying to raise the number of machines to see if it can fit my data set. BTW, can you please let me know how to dump out the failed row in spark when I get such error? I really don't sure what's wrong with my program now because it always throw an error saying it try to handle a row for 5 times and then it fail. And I can't see which row is wrong.

Comment: I tried to use 10 core instance and 10 task instance to run my script, but still getting same exception, it's only running 3 minutes more. Is it an improvement ? If yes, I may try to use more instance

Comment: Now it seems to me that the problem lies with the MongoDB query rather than the Spark. Can you please try cheking the `queryPlanner` and `executionStats` as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: The thing is , I don't have permission to query on that database directly . I will ask devops team for help. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, will spark get stack overflow error if the query is slow? This query don't have index on these two fields , so I guess the query will be quite slow, but I though it should only throw timeoutexception , not stack overflow.

Comment: I think it's the query that makes it too slow and generate the exception. DevOps have to wait for the query for more than 15 minutes after it is started.... BTW, this is my final question. Will mongo connector query the load the whole table into the memory and then do the query or just parse the sql I written and then do the query on mongo?

Comment: As far as I know, Spark picks only the data it needs and then process it. Check this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/tutorial-for-operationalizing-spark-with-mongodb).

Comment: I tried to use another query which is faster,but it still throw me same error ,just in a shorter time. I will take a deeper look into this problem, looks like it's not about the large table. So I won't have a further discussion here. Thanks for your help. Maybe I will answer my question when I figure out which part is going wrong. But still , great thanks for your help.